# Extending an HTMLProps interface throws error of incorrectly extending interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

I'm trying to  extend an interface to imported from react, but I'm gettting an error: `TS2430: Interface 'IProps' incorrectly extends interface 'HTMLProps<HTMLTableCellElement>'.`.

This is my complete code and the error message:

```
import cx from 'classnames';
import { HTMLProps } from 'react';

import styles from './index.module.scss';

export interface IProps extends HTMLProps<HTMLTableCellElement> {
  title?: string;
  className?: string;
  wrap?: boolean;
}

export const Th = ({ title, className, wrap, ...rest }: IProps) => {
  return (
    <th
      data-title={title}
      {...rest}
      className={cx(wrap && styles.wrap, className)}
    />
  );
};
```

And the **error** message:

```
ERROR in.../Th.tsx:6:18
TS2430: Interface 'IProps' incorrectly extends interface 'HTMLProps<HTMLTableCellElement>'.
  Types of property 'wrap' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    4 | import styles from './index.module.scss';
    5 |
  > 6 | export interface IProps extends HTMLProps<HTMLTableCellElement> {
      |                  ^^^^^^
    7 |   title?: string;
    8 |   className?: string;
    9 |   wrap?: boolean;
```

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to import all the types from  `HTMLProps<HTMLTableCellElement>` but add new ones such as `wrap, ...etc`.  I think the error comes from the fact that `className` is already defined as an `string` inside `HTMLProps<HTMLTableCellElement>` and I cannot redefined this ?

**What I'm expecting:** I was expecting to be able to extend types from imported interfaces. I do **not** want to override the imported types.

Comment: `wrap` already exists [on the textarea element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attributes). Therefore, you should not overwrite it. Name your prop something else, like `shouldWrap` or `wrapped`.

Comment: That solved the issue thanks @pink. If you post this as an answer, I will mark it as approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error here because it appears that `HTMLProps` includes [the `wrap` attribute on textareas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attributes). I'm not exactly sure if it's specifically from textareas, though (it seems like `wrap` is supported for most text elements). Since this is a `boolean` on textarea elements, re-typing it to a `string` is invalid. An easy workaround would be to just rename the prop:

```
export interface IProps extends HTMLProps<HTMLTableCellElement> {
    title?: string;
    className?: string;
    shouldWrapText?: boolean; // okay
}

export const Th = ({ title, className, shouldWrapText, ...rest }: IProps) => {
    return (
        <th
            data-title={title}
            {...rest}
            className={cx(shouldWrapText && styles.wrap, className)}
        />
    );
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAYwB5wGZQiOAiBAbAQwGciA7AkAUyOwG4AoUSWOAJUoIRgBo4BvOAAkAKgFkAMgAUMYInAC+aDFmxQOXOvQD0WgAIwiAWmABzUtEqNw0eERgBPPNSWYcAOi3BSAE0pI3IBDeAK5ObkQIJJr0fszwXjCUUKiclHAAktIQsnB+iT5yIhJZsgA8ReLCBABGTgDClHh4AKJOVKQwAHz89HB9cDDAME4A-ABccHZQXiYM-YiEJAByFJTjkzDTpLO9-UQAFhCh3gDqUARgwnnr1RAQTgSktHA6cBAA1gT29PL0MUhxRAQUh2ODCfZwAC8cAAFAJBsNKLx8MQiCsqLwDkc8Kdzpc8rw3ES1KD5BNMjIiABKKHdPi7PpqGDBKCkWEM+ZwUowfYczn9bwEGAEQwIpyQvhiyi-fn8vhEtwkmAy2XzFHLVYS5AwrHHM4XK5IeAAMmNG0c1DcAHc8cjFmjVlSVfytJ0OVSGPIGEA)